# What will be the time complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

what will be the time complexity for the following code?
I calculate it like n²log(n)

```java
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < N/2; j++)
     for (int k = 1; k < N;)
     {
       x++;
       k *= 2;
     }
return x;
```

Comment: Indeed, it is like you say.

Comment: n2 lg(n) is wrong, the complexity is O(n3)

Comment: for (int k = 1; k < N;)
     {
       x++;
       k *= 2;
     }  what is the time complexity for this one so I thought it was log(n)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct!

Number of times the **first** loop executes = **N**.

Number of times the **second** loop executes = **N/2**.

Number of times the **third** loop executes = **log2(N)**.

Therefore, time complexity = O(N * (N/2) * log2(N)) = O((N^2)/2 * log2(N)).

After neglecting constants for the highest power of N, **time complexity = O((N^2) * log2(N)).**